# Contact form issues

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I'm having all kinds of issues with contact form. When I test on my home server everything runs smoothly. Once I upload it online it doesn't work. First there were problems with headers and now apparently "This web page has a redirect loop".

Here's my code. Please advice me what to do. 
Thanks.

```
<?php
// Title: Contact Form - Dolce Forno GB
// Updated: 5/9/2012

//Validation code
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$errors = array();

//variables
$name      = $_POST['name'];
$email     = $_POST['email'];
$phone     = $_POST['phone'];
$subject   = $_POST['subject'];
$message   = $_POST['message'];

//All field are required
if (empty($name) === true || empty($email) === true || empty($phone) === true ||   empty($subject) === true || empty($message) === true ){
    $errors[] = 'Please fill in all the fields.';
}
    else {
        //This regex allows only: a-z,A-Z, space, comma, full stop, apostrophe, dash
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\s,.'-]+$/", $name)) { 
            $errors[] = 'Invalid name.'; 
            /*die ("Invalid name."); */
        }
        //var_filter php function
        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Invalid email address.'; 
        }
        //This regex allows only: 0-9, space, dash, brackets, min-max length: 10-15
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9\s]{10,15}$/", $phone)){
            $errors[] = 'Invalid phone number.';
        }
    }
}
if (empty($errors)) {
    //send email
    mail('info@dolcefornogb.com', 'Contact Form', $subject, 'Message:' . $message,'From: ' . $name . $email . $phone);
    header('Location:mail.php?sent');
    exit ();
}
print_r($errors);

?>

<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['sent']) === true) {
    echo '<p>Thanks for contacting us!</p>';
}
else {
    if (!empty($errors)){
        echo    '<ul>';

        foreach ($errors as $error){
            echo '<li>', $error,'</li>';

        echo    '</ul>';
        }
    }
?>
        <form action="" method="post">

        <p> <label for="name">Name 
        <span class="small">Add your name </span></label> 
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" 
        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['name']) === true){
            echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['name']),'"';
        }
        ?>
        >
        </p>
        <p> <label for="email">E-mail address
        <span class="small"> Add your e-mail</span></label> 
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"
        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['email']) === true){
            echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['email']),'"';
        }
        ?>          
        >
        </p>
        <p><label for="phone">Phone<span class="small"> Add your phone number</span></label> 
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"
        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['phone']) === true){
            echo 'value="', ($_POST['phone']),'"';
        }
        ?>
        >
        </p>
        <p><label for="suject">Subject </label> 
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject"
        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['subject']) === true){
            echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['subject']),'"';
        }
        ?>
        >
        </p>
        <p><label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="messgae" rows="10" cols="50"> 
        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['message']) === true){
            echo strip_tags($_POST['message']);
        }
        ?></textarea> 
        </p>
        <p><label for="call">Request Phone Call</label>
        Yes:<input type="radio" value="Yes" name="call">
        No:<input type="radio" value="No" name="call">
        </p>
        <p class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" value="Send"> <input type="reset" value="Clear">
        </p>
        </form>
<?php       
}

?>
```

Comment: You don't have to exit after redirect user.

Comment: Use Firebug or Chrome Dev tools to watch the requests when you submit the form to see if it is redirecting in a loop. @CanVural there is nothing wrong with exit() and it is present after the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting to a different page with just the success message in it.

i.e. replace

```
header('Location:mail.php?sent');
```

with

```
header('Location:mail-success.php?sent');
```

Then get rid of (move to the new page)

```
if (isset($_GET['sent']) === true) {
    echo '<p>Thanks for contacting us!</p>';
}
```

Also try adding 303 status to the header call

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-303-redirect/

Comment: I'm lost. Do you know about any good guide how to create a php contact form?

Comment: http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/php-contact-form-tutorial.html includes sample code and looks OK

Comment: I tried it, but there're are deprecated functions like eregi and split in the code. Also there's a problem with: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent.

Comment: You can turn off deprecated warnings for now using `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);`

Comment: Headers already sent is most commonly caused by white space after the php closing tag ?>, (either new lines or spaces)